# How to create one data frame out of two where same timestamp pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two pandas dataFrames:

```
fileX = pd.DataFrame({'cas':pd.date_range('2017-03-02 22:52:00', periods=5, freq='T'),
                      'hodnota': [[1]] * 5})
fileX.cas = fileX.cas.dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M')
print (fileX)
                cas hodnota
0  2017-03-02 22:52     [1]
1  2017-03-02 22:53     [1]
2  2017-03-02 22:54     [1]
3  2017-03-02 22:55     [1]
4  2017-03-02 22:56     [1]

real = pd.DataFrame({'timeStampRoundedToMinute':pd.date_range('2017-03-02 22:52:00', 
                                                              periods=5, freq='T'),
                      'received_optical_power': [-25.0] * 5,
                      'binary_y':[1] * 5})
real = real[['timeStampRoundedToMinute','received_optical_power','binary_y']]
real.timeStampRoundedToMinute = real.timeStampRoundedToMinute.dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M')
print (real)
  timeStampRoundedToMinute  received_optical_power  binary_y
0         2017-03-02 22:52                   -25.0         1
1         2017-03-02 22:53                   -25.0         1
2         2017-03-02 22:54                   -25.0         1
3         2017-03-02 22:55                   -25.0         1
4         2017-03-02 22:56                   -25.0         1
```

I take **real** as the reference so my goal is to take all values 
from both **real** and **fileX** dataframes   where the **cas** == **timeStampRoundedToMinute**.

I was able to do something like that :

```
output = real[real.timeStampRoundedToMinute.isin(fileX['cas'])]
print (output)
  timeStampRoundedToMinute  received_optical_power  binary_y
0         2017-03-02 22:52                   -25.0         1
1         2017-03-02 22:53                   -25.0         1
2         2017-03-02 22:54                   -25.0         1
3         2017-03-02 22:55                   -25.0         1
4         2017-03-02 22:56                   -25.0         1
```

so I am missing one more column in **output dataframe** with **hodnota**
column which belongs to the **fileX** dataframe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you need [`merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.merge.html) with default `inner` join:

```
df = pd.merge(fileX, real, left_on='cas', right_on='timeStampRoundedToMinute')
```

Comment: Thank you so much!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! I have been struggling with that problem for a while and I knew that has to have a simple solution. Thanks!!!!

Comment: and small advice - [Don't post images of code (or links to them)](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: btw, I round to `minutes` by `strftime`, if I am wrong, you can change it in your question.

Comment: It is supposed to be **round** to minutes, however now I am trying to get rid of [1] square brackets in **hodnota** column in **fileX** dataframe. Can you perhaps advise on that ??

I tried df['hodnota'].str.get(0) 

as well as few other options like **lstrip** and **rstrip** non of them worked for me.

Comment: Yes, it is ok, another solution is `df['hodnota'].str[0]`.

Comment: I tried `df['hodnota'].str[0]`
as well as 
`df['hodnota'] = df['hodnota'].str.strip('[]')` however I still have **left** bracket on the output

Comment: Do you need `fileX.cas = fileX.cas.dt.round('T')` ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137273/discussion-between-jezrael-and-user2156115).

Comment: I actually do not need **round** option because **real** is the **MySQL** select and **fileX** comes from **text file** predictions using **sklearn**

Comment: maybe help [chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137273/discussion-between-jezrael-and-user2156115)